# What is the difference between non-free and non-free-firmware in Debian 12?

Tags: debian, package-management, repository

The Debian project has included a new repository component `non-free-firmware` in Debian bookworm.

Is it the same as the `non-free` repository ?

Do I need to activate the new component alongside of the old `non-free` in my `sources.list`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `non-free` and `non-free-firmware` are not the same repositories and if you want both, you need to activate both.

The decision to create `non-free-firmware` was taken as firmware very often does not meet the Debian Free Software Guidelines. However, in many cases is quite cumbersome (if not impossible) to be replaced/avoided for having a usable system. Free software often cannot keep pace with whatever drivers etc. are needed.

It was also decided, that the option to exclude `non-free` software that is not a basic requirement to have a running PC should still be present. Thus the respective software packages remain in `non-free`.

Note that since Bookworm `non-free-firmware` is a default part of installation media, whereas `non-free` is not. This is also different from previous installation images, where non-free software was generally excluded.

Comment: See also [the section descriptions](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages).

Comment: Maybe it's worth adding to the answer that `non-free-firmware` is added by default to the installation media since Bookworm. For previous versions there were alternative IM downloads for non free firmware.